# Angular app not working if modules not imported into routing module

Tags: angular, typescript

I have some very weird behavior and don't know where it is coming from. I wanted to clean up my code and therefore I created a module for each component and a routing module which handles all the routes.

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { LoginComponent } from '@features/authentication/login/login.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path     : 'auth/login',
        component: LoginComponent
    },
];

@NgModule({
    imports : [
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
    ],
    exports : [
        RouterModule
    ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**login.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { MatFormFieldModule} from '@angular/material/button';

import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        LoginComponent
    ],
    imports     : [
        RouterModule,
        MatFormFieldModule,
    ]
})
export class LoginModule
{
}
```

And in the `app.module.ts` I simply import the the `app-routing.module.ts`. However, for some reason it always tells me that `'mat-form-field' is not a known element`. If I import the `login.module.ts` into the `app-routing.module.ts` it works fine. I don't understand why I need to import it though...

**Edit: (app.module.ts)**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { CoreModule } from '@core/core.module';
import { LayoutModule } from 'app/layout/layout.module';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module'

import { AppComponent } from 'app/app.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports     : [
        // Browser
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,

        // App modules
        CoreModule,
        LayoutModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
    ],
    bootstrap   : [
        AppComponent
    ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: What does app.module.ts look like?

Comment: If you are going to break everything down into modules I would recommend lazy loading them in the app.routing file. Not sure if it will solve your problem, but it may

Comment: Thanks for your help. I found out that I don't even have to add it to the imports array of the routing module. Only doing the import makes it work already. Also after doing that my path aliases get resolved. This is some really weird behavior...

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your modules import tree, it looks something like this

- AppModule -> (Imports) -> AppRoutingModule -> (Uses) -> LoginComponent
- LoginModule -> (Declares) -> LoginComponent

See how you are Using and Declaring LoginComponent from two totally isolated branches, AppModule does not know of LoginComponent so does not have access to it.

LoginComponent is only declared (and therefore accessible) from LoginModule.

I would suggest exporting your LoginComponent if you want it to be accessible from outside LoginModule and Importing your LoginModule in AppModule to give it access to LoginComponent. this changes your tree like this :

- AppModule

  (Imports) -> AppRoutingModule -> (Uses) -> LoginComponent

  (Imports) -> LoginModule -> (Declares/Exports) -> LoginComponent

Now AppModule knows about the declaration of LoginComponent and has access to it and would be able to create an instance of it when its route needs it.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { MatFormFieldModule} from '@angular/material/button';

import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        LoginComponent
    ],
    imports     : [
        RouterModule,
        MatFormFieldModule,
    ],
    exports : [
      LoginComponent
   ]
})
export class LoginModule
{
}
```

and

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { CoreModule } from '@core/core.module';
import { LayoutModule } from 'app/layout/layout.module';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module'

import { AppComponent } from 'app/app.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports     : [
        // Browser
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,

        // App modules
        CoreModule,
        LayoutModule,
        AppRoutingModule,

        LoginModule,
    ],
    bootstrap   : [
        AppComponent
    ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Also depending on the exact use case of your app, I highly recommend looking into lazyloading your modules if they are tied to a specific route https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules